# I am not the first

Tags: riddle

```
I am not the first. 
To some I am the second. 
To others I am the third. 
But I'm never the fourth.

I am the first. 
I'm no help in "a way out." 
But I'm first in these words: "I", "don't", "know".

I can't be left alone. 
If I'm alone, I will offend someone. 
You can't make peace if you cut me off. 
But on the other hand, you might.
```

I was inspired by [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55985/driving-me-crazy/55988#55988) riddle by [Mello](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41606/mello), so I wanna give him props.

Comment: something about the letter "I" maybe? ..

Comment: I can see what you mean, but I think the fist line rules a locational pattern out though. Here, I've modified the second section to be a little more clear. I'll add a hint later if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it's

> Your middle finger

Reasoning:

> It's either second or third, depending on if you start with the thumb or not.  The second clue is where the middle finger falls when typing.  The third clue - a middle finger alone is offensive, and if you cut off the middle finger on one hand, you can't make a peace sign, but then you can always make a peace sign with the other hand

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! I've taken the liberty to edit the post so that it is not completely spoilered.

Comment: Excellent! I'm marking yours as the answer because you got all the clues, specifically, the second clue. No one else got that one. =)

Answer (score 18):

You are:

> my middle finger

I am not the first.
To some I am the second.
To others I am the third.
But I'm never the fourth.

> Counting from the index finger to pinky, the middle finger is the second. Counting from pinky to index, it is third. It will never be first or fourth (in a complete hand, anyway).

I am the first. 
I'm no help in "a way out." 
But I'm first in these words: "I", "don't", "know".

> I missed this one entirely. See Matt's answer for the correct interpretation.

I can't be left alone. 
If I'm alone, I will offend someone.

> The middle finger on its own is an insult.

You can't make peace if you cut me off.

> The peace sign requires both the index and middle fingers.

But on the other hand, you might.

> I believe this is just a pun on "hand".

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Why don't you take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)?